# how to modify this python for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

i'm having strange behavior from the for loop in python. The problem is not exactly this one but very similar to :

```
a = []
b = [1,2,3,4]
for i in xrange (0,10):
     a.append(b)
     b[3] += 1
```

And the result is :

```
a = [[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14],[1,2,3,14]]
```

The result i'm expecting is

```
a =  [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[1,2,3,7],.....,[1,2,3,14]]
```

I do not know why at each iteration, b[3] is added up to 14 and then the list [1,2,3,14] is added to a. I think b[3] should only increase by 1 at each iteration

Comment: This is because you are appending a reference to `b` to `a` at each iteration of the loop, not a copy of `b`. Each reference points to the same `b`, which, at the end of your loop, has `b[3] = 14`.

Comment: Try pasting the code in [this python code visualizer](http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit) to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @lazyr That is really helpful - glad I know about this now!

Comment: Thank a lot all of you guy :))

Comment: @lazyr wow, there are even such things, but seems it is problematic, because even for simple code segments as such, it crashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that every iteration you append a reference to the same array, and keep changing it.

The simplest fix is to change the append to

```
 a.append(list(b))
```

This will make every iteration append a (shallow) copy to the target array, instead of a reference.

Answer (score 4):

`b` is accessed by reference, so when you modify `b[3]` it's affecting every reference of it that you've appended to  `a` over and over again.  To fix this you just need to create a new copy of `b` each time:

```
a = []
b = [1,2,3,4]
for i in xrange (0,10):
     a.append(b[:])
     b[3] += 1
```

Comment: list(b) is much more novice friendly syntax for b[:]

Answer (score 2):

you can use `deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = []
b = [1,2,3,4]
for i in xrange (0,10):
     a.append(deepcopy(b))
     b[3] += 1
```